# SQL: How to Order By the attributes in Descending but second character of it need to be Ascending Order

Tags: mysql, heidisql

How to produce this output in MySQL?

Sort the albums first based on the album format in descending order followed by the tracks in ascending order.

[image]

I can come out the output with this command:

```
SELECT album_singer, album_name, album_format_name, album_tracks
FROM album, album_format
WHERE album.Album_Type_ID = album_format.Album_Format_ID
ORDER BY album_format_name DESC, album_tracks ASC
```

Output that I can produce:

```
Vinyl
Vinyl
Digital
Compact Disc
Compact Disc
Compact Disc
Compact Disc
Compact Disc
Cassette
Cassette
```

Output that I need:

```
Vinyl
Vinyl
Digital
Cassette
Cassette
Compact Disc
Compact Disc
Compact Disc
Compact Disc
Compact Disc
```

Comment: Is this [tag:sql-server] or [tag:mysql]? The question is currently tagged with both?

Comment: thank you for helping me edit the looks. I not familiar with this sorry, this is my first time posting the question.

Comment: I recommend using explicit joins rather than implicit ones - its considered best practise, and it clearer to understand.

Comment: Noted, thanks. Btw this is mySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL's [`field`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) is very useful for custom ordering like your expected output requires.
Additionally, as Dale K mentioned in the comments, implicit joins (having more than one item in the `from` clause) is an outdated practice, and you should probably use an explicit `join` clause:

```sql
SELECT   album_singer, album_name, album_format_name, album_tracks
FROM     album
JOIN     album_format ON album.Album_Type_ID = album_format.Album_Format_ID
ORDER BY FIELD(album_format_name, 'Vinyl', 'Digital', 'Cassette', 'Compact Disc'), 
         album_tracks ASC
```

Comment: I learned from my lecturer who told me this way to write the command. Thank you to inform me that it was outdated. Really thanks a lot.